# How to change the Zabbix access address for port 10051?

Tags: apache-http-server, zabbix

The issue involves zabbix and apache, I already tested some settings and could not solve. Zabbix is ​​installed within a certain interface, eg domain.com/zabbix and I would like to change to domain.com:10051 is it possible?

I am using apache as a web server and tried to change the respective zabbix settings to the alias inside the directory: /etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem to be a useful change - port 10051 is the Zabbix server (trapper) port. While you could move Zabbix to a non-standard port, and then the web UI to port 10051, it would be mighty confusing and does not seem to provide any benefit.

Comment: I'll be more specific, I need to put zabbix on an external domain of the company, which in this case will be a subdomain of the main domain (site). It will be like this: monitor.domain.com.br there should be zabbix for both external and internal access.

However, the domain/ip already responds on the default port 80, in this case it must be another port. So when I access from outside the company I have to be able to access the monitor.domain.com.br. It does not make a difference to the other port, I just released port 10051 on the router, but I can release other

Comment: So the question is not about Zabbix, but about web servers. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html for setting up virtual hosts. I'd recommend port 443 with encryption, although you might want to set up an unencrypted version first to practice. Note that exposing Zabbix UI to the internet is risky.